# Any way to disable plasmashell startup for Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, startup, plasma-5, kde5

I'm using a hybrid KDE+i3wm setup and was thinking of moving to `polybar`. So I was wondering if it is possible to inform KDE not to start `plasmashell` when running `exec startplasma-x11` in `~/.xsession`.

I can close `plasmashell` using `kquitapp5 plasmashell` but don't know how to execute this before startup.

I want the transition to be smooth, that is, `plasmashell` shouldn't load and then close, since it eats up startup time.

Comment: you should be able to run this after a delay (with sleep?) in your .Xsession file.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a hacky way. The sleep duration would have to be modified from time to time. I hope a neat way exists for this.

Answer (score 3):

I use bspwm alongside the plasma DE myself, I understand your problem, I could never find a way to stop plasmashell from opening at startup even with the setting (StartupandShutdown->DesktopSession->OnLogin->StartWithAnEmptySession)

I made a small script that runs for one minute and searches for the pid of plasmashell then runs a kill command, its not the best fix but it fixes the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

run="1 minute"
end=$(date -ud "$run" +%s)

while [[ $(date -u +%s) -le $end ]]
do
        plasma=$(pgrep plasmashell)
        kill "$plasma"
        sleep 10
done
```

Just make a .sh file and add to autostart in the KDE settings manager,you can change the overall run time as needed for your login time.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

plasma without plasma? does not seems to make sense to me.
what piece of KDE do you want to run ?

for my, the minimal KDE Plasma desktop is

- plasmashell (background + widgets + panel)
- kwin (the window manager)
- krunner

I am guessing you don't need kwin if you run i3
plasma without a panel, only for the background under i3 sounds unlikely to be working nicely together...

then krunner, obviously optional whenever you like. so I really wonder? what pieces you desire running?

I think you just want to run i3 and open KDE applications. no need to start any KDE/plasma initializer.

just open the apps you want

- kate
- cantata
- dolphin
- konsole

to name a few

sorry if I miss-understood your questions.

I hope this helps

Comment: I want KDE's daemons and bus services only

Comment: For example, I like the power options displayed by KDE

Comment: that should be a fun adventure, you could try running `dbus-daemon & ksmserver & kglobalaccel5`, kded5 should start automatically. I think you are heading in unexplore territory and if you succeed, I encourage you to post a blog post and a youtube stream about it. cheers.

Comment: Hmm, seems worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

plasmashell is started from a desktop entry located in `/etc/xdg/autostart`. On Arch, it is named `org.kde.plasmashell.desktop`. You can override that entry with your own inside your user config home.

Simply create an empty desktop entry in `~/.config/autostart` with the same name as the one in `/etc/xdg/autostart` with the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Hidden=true
```

This should disable plasmashell completely.

Reference: https://github.com/KDE/liquidshell/blob/580fe59033aed807ccaf4b7418b60ff2357fa80b/start_liquidshell

### Edit for KDE 5.25:

Since KDE 5.25, Plasma services are started with systemd user units. Masking the unit will disable plasmashell.

```
systemctl --user mask --now plasma-plasmashell.service
```